# Ways to profile a java application for jdk7

Tags: java, profiling, java-7, javaagents

I have been profiling my java application with javaagent. but i find that JDK 7 tightened up the checks performed on stack map frames which can lead to VerifyError exceptions when the bytecode has been modified by tools unaware of these changes. we can use -XX:-UseSplitVerifier" switch to change the verifier back to JDK 6 version. but i find the execution time for the java application without javaagent is comparitively less than the same java application run by javaagent. Are there any other way to profile? JVMTI provides a better option but i'm not very good with native(c,c++) languages.

Comment: ....you mean apart from using a commercial/open-source profiler?

Comment: yes radai i'm looking into developing my own profiler.

Answer (score 3):

You can try jvisualvm which is included in the oracle jdk

(If you are using JDK version 6, update 7 or above)

> but i find the execution time for the java application without javaagent is comparitively less than the same java application run by javaagent

Any profiler will have some amount of overhead (if it's doing something it has to be using the cpu and some memory itself)

Comment: thanks msam and ajduke. i'm looking into developing my own profiler using Java. so was in a way searching for any API's or agents which has very low overhead.

Comment: In that case you might want to look [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers) and see what is already available

Answer (score 2):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) works well with Java 7.